# Expect_background and EOF Problems

Tags: expect

When I run a script, similar to below, I get an error of "expect: spawn id exp4 not open".

```
spawn sqlplus instuser/*******  @script

expect "Enter the password for SYSTEM:"
send "********\r"

expect_background {
  "Test pattern 1" {
    set testa 1
  }
  "Test pattern 2" {
    set testb 1
  }
  "Test pattern 3" {
    set testc 1
  }
}

expect eof
# Do more after
```

If I remove the expect eof, then expect terminates before the script completes. How do I use expect_background, and have it read until the process terminates? I looked all over and can't find the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the `@script` actually exit from sqlplus? Do you need to expect the sqlplus prompt and then send `exit\r` and *then* expect eof?

Comment: The script exits SQL by itself, there's no need to send exit\r. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `exp_internal 1` to enable debug output, and see if that gives you more clues about when that error is emitted.

Comment: What's your purpose? What problems are you solving?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will test the solution during the next database migration we have as the primary purpose of the script is to intelligently install database packages after the migration. I'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: @pynexj I still haven't been able to test the solution yet, but I haven't forgotten about it. I was expecting the next database migration to occur sooner. Once that's finished, I will have to review my scripts and then, I can test the solution. The problem is that I need the old data for the scripts to work. Urg. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're really doing but you can use Tcl's [vwait](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/vwait.htm) for this. See following example:

```
[STEP 102] # cat foo.exp
set forever {}

spawn bash -c {for i in {1..5}; do echo foo$i; sleep 1; done}

expect_background {
    something {
        do something
    }
    eof {
        set forever 1
    }
}

vwait forever
wait
[STEP 103] # expect foo.exp
spawn bash -c for i in {1..5}; do echo foo$i; sleep 1; done
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
[STEP 104] #
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made some modifications to your code and it work beautifully.